# Access How to use Me.Filter cmd

Tags: ms-access, filter

I have a question dealing with a filter function.

I am fine when using a button to search if there is any related data when I entered a keyword. And my code like,

```
Private Sub Command112_Click()
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim strFilter As String

    strSearch = "'*" & Forms![TestForm].SearchInput & "*'"
    Debug.Print strSearch

    strFilter = _
    "[IMSDP] Like " & strSearch & _
                " Or [EN8] Like " & strSearch & _
                " Or [EN10] Like " & strSearch & _
                " Or [Card] Like " & strSearch & _
                " Or [Status] Like " & strSearch & _
                " Or [IMSDP] Like " & strSearch

    Debug.Print strFilter

    Me.Filter = strFilter
    Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

But once I want to search more than one keyword, it doesn't work.
And my code like following,

```
Private Sub Search_Click()

    Dim strSearch As Variant
    Dim strFilter1 As Variant
    Dim strFilter2 As Variant
    Dim SpacePosition As Variant
    Dim Lstr As Variant
    Dim Rstr As Variant
    Dim IMSDP1 As Variant
    Dim IMSDP2 As Variant

    strSearch = "'*" & Forms![tryForm].IMSDPInput & "*'"
    Debug.Print strSearch

    SpacePosition = InStr(1, [strSearch], " ")
    Lstr = Trim(Left([strSearch], [SpacePosition] - 1))
    Rstr = Trim(Right([strSearch], Len([strSearch]) - [SpacePosition]))

    IMSDP1 = Lstr
    IMSDP2 = Rstr

    MsgBox "IMSDP1 is " & IMSDP1 & " and IMSDP2 is " & IMSDP2 & ""

    strFilter1 = _
    "[IMSDP] Like " & IMSDP1 & _
    "And [IMSDP] Like " & IMSDP2

    Me.Filter = strFilter
    Me.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

Can anyone help? Thank you.

I am now having the code like follow, (you may think Status = IMSDP)

```
Private Sub Command14_Click()
Dim Status_Filter As Variant
Dim Status_Input As Variant
Dim SpacePosition As Variant
Dim Status1 As Variant
Dim Status2 As Variant

Status_Input = "'*" & Forms![tryForm].StatusInput & "*'"
SpacePosition = InStr(1, [Status_Input], " ")

If (SpacePosition = 0) Then
    Status_Filter = _
      "[Status] Like " & Status_Input

Else
    Status1 = Left([Status_Input], [SpacePosition] - 1)
    Status2 = Right([Status_Input], Len([Status_Input]) - [SpacePosition])

    MsgBox "Status1 is " & Status1 & " and Status2 is " & Status2 & ""

    Status_Filter = _
       "[Status] Like " & Status1 & _
       "Or [Status] Like " & Status2

End If

Debug.Print Status_Filter
Me.Filter = Status_Filter
Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

It works if I only enter one keyword(e.g. "20") to search but fail if I entering something like "20 27".

I only know I can write in Excel like, Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Status1, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=Status2 But I have no idea how to do it in Access

Comment: It sounds like you want to pick records where `[IMSDP]` is like `IMSDP1` **OR** it is like `IMSDP2` - it doesn't sound like you want it to be "like" both of them.  (E.g. `"ABCDE" Like "ABC*" And "ABCDE" Like "XYZ*"` will be False because it isn't like `"XYZ*"`, but `"ABCDE" Like "ABC*" Or "ABCDE" Like "XYZ*"` will be True because it is like `"ABC*"`)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Do you mean I cant make Me.FilterOn = True since I have two scenarios? 

What I am looking for is, I got a very big database and one of the columns named "IMSDP" (and which is containing information like ABDAM91, YCKAE02 etc., the format is like this.). This program is writing to let user to enter the words like, "ABD Or 91 Or AE (which equal to strSearch in above code) " and search from the column [IMSDP].

Comment: Ah... yup ... I want the OR but not AND. But it still doesnt work even I changed it. Sorry, I really new in this area, just self-learning.

Comment: LIKE without wildcard might as well be just equal sign. You are using a single textbox for users to enter any text? This is just a single string of characters. Converting that single string to a filter criteria statement can be done by parsing to an array. Is Status a text field?

Comment: Thank you June7,
Yes, I am using one text box for user to enter any text and status is number actually.

Since I am not good in code, therefore I just trying to get the string from the user input and separate it into two parts, let say user enter to status to search. So that I can do filtering in those parts.

Do you think it is possible? Hope you understand what I am saying,

Comment: Put a space in front of the "Or " so the construct doesn't run together: `" Or "`. Use = sign instead of LIKE. If you want to allow any number of values, use an array.

Answer (score 1):

If Status field is number type and users always enter 'keywords' separated by a space, consider the following:

```
Private Sub Command14_Click()
If Not IsNull(Me.StatusInput) Then
   Me.Filter = "IN(" & Replace(Me.StatusInput, " ", ",") & ")"
End If
Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

If they enter separated with comma, even simpler:
`Me.Filter = "IN(" Me.StatusInput & ")"`

For a text field:
`"IN('" & Replace(Me.StatusInput, " ", "','") & "')"`

`"IN('" & Replace(Me.StatusInput, ",", "','") & "')"`

Regardless of code structure, depends on users entering string in textbox correctly and consistently.

If you want more control over the values user can enter, use a multi-select listbox and VBA loops through the listbox selected items to construct the comma separated values criteria. A fairly common topic and many code examples available for looping listbox.

And no array needed after all!

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems good, but it said there is a syntax error(missing operator) in query expression IN(__,__).
Also, may I know, how can I compare with my database to look for the input that I get from Me.Filter? Is it why I got a syntax error?

Comment: Why is there only a comma? If the textbox has anything other than Null then the code will attempt to build the criteria. Looks like there is only a space. As I said, depends on educating users on what and how to enter text. The method works for me.

Comment: Um .. Actually it is IN(20,27) since my input is 20 and 27. 
Thank you for providing me this method, I think it is good but I dunno know how to handle it even it is what I should do.
I only finish one which can input one or two or three status to search but fail in building one which can handle more than three inputs.
And I found I am facing another problem. For status which is a two digits number for my case, but if I need to search a string like  "ABDAE91 ABDAM02", "*" & [Forms]![tryForm]![IMSDP_Input] & "*" doesn't work for me to separate into two parts using Left() and Right() function.

Comment: So IN(20,27) is not working? Why do you not know how to handle? I provided the procedure and it works for me. You have two fields you want to do this with? It's a little trickier with text field.